# trying to setup ubuntu14 with Windows 10

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-10

I already have Windows 10 installed.  I created the recovery drive for Windows.  I turned off fast boot but did not turn off safe login.  I created a partition using Windows partition manager.  I then used the Ubuntu installation flash drive to create three partitions (2 ext4 for "/" and "/home" and one for swap space).  The installation seemed to have gone fine.
When I start the computer, the boot loader only boots up Windows 10.  I tried BC Edit with Windows 8.1 and was able to get it working though not perfectly.  I read up that perhaps I should not have to use EasyBCD with Windows10.  Any ideas on how I can modify the boot loader to ensure that I can launch either Windows 10 or Ubuntu 14 (on a HP laptop).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the default operating system to boot from Windows to Ubuntu in **BIOS / UEFI**.
If this is not possible or doesn't work with expected results proceed with the following steps:

First you have to **disable hibernation** in Windows - as you said **Fast Boot** is **disabled already**.

Boot into Windows - open **command prompt as administrator** and execute this command:

```
powercfg /h off
```

**Shutdown** the machine (do **NOT reboot**) completely.

Then reinstall GRUB bootloader to your Ubuntu installation  in **EFI mode**.

Boot from the Ubuntu install media - then  open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sd*** /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sd*
update-grub
```

Note :

`sd*` = disk | `sd**` = efi partition | `sd***` = system partition

In case you have an older machine with **legacy BIOS** the commands are:

```
sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt  
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sd*
```

Note : `sd*` = disk | `sd**` = system partition

If you do not know the partition numbers you can easily identify them with **GParted**.

This (Graphic User Interface) tool is already included in the Ubuntu installation media.

Comment: @user3813256 : What I did not mention in my answer : I recommend to uninstall EasyBCD before because these kind of 3rd party tools tend to generate problems later when you want to change or delete boot loaders. When working on the BCD store in Windows you better should use the built-in tool "bcdedit". :)

Comment: thanks - changing sage login and modifying the boot entry option allowed me to boot ubuntu.  still need to check windows installation.  Did not try the steps above  Thanks for sharing

Comment: I actually did not follow the answer as per my comment - I just thanked you for sharing (not being nasty).  Your input probably does work for a lot of the cases (I did not need to use it on my computer).  I upvoted it